# automatic versioning with Parcel.js?

Tags: web-applications, version-control, semantic-versioning, parcel, parceljs

I'm using Parcel.js to build and pack an application that I currently support developing. Every time I create a build, after a small modification, I need to update the minor version of the application: **v.1.2.34** -> **1.2.35**, in *package.json* file. The version number appears somewhere inside the application menu, is important for the team/customer, so we really need to do this every time we change something.

Is there a way to auto counter/increase the version number when I build it with Parcel ?
I mean to write this increment in *package.json* or elsewhere will be fine.

Tx in advance.